# Foreach ADO Enumerator doesn't show ADO object source variable

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ado.net

I have like 1 hour of SSIS experience so I do not know why this is failing.

[I am following this guide](https://coldlogics.wordpress.com/2011/04/09/using-ssis-to-dynamically-create-data-files-from-a-full-result-set/).

However when I get to the Foreach loop editor screen section and pick "Foreach ADO enumerator" I cannot see the ADO Object source variable section.

[image]

The screen should look like this

[image]

Any ideas?

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and a release candidate of SSDT so this may be an issue.

I have followed all steps correctly and have seen no errors in previous steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched for this issue and i found two simple suggestions:

- Try running visual studio in Safe mode using this command *(this issue can be caused by a third-party add-on)*

  ```
  devenv.exe /safemode
  ```
- Try repairing your SQL Server Data Tools installation or Download the **[Latest release](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx)**

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue; here's how I solved it:

If your package was developed in SQL 2014:

Right click **Solution** in **Solution Explorer** of **Data Tools** ->

**Properties** -> **Configuration Properties** -> **General** -> **Change Target Version**.

Answer (score 5):

The SSIS ADO Enumerator was blank for me too.

For the latest version of SSDT [Release 17.0] [Build 14.0] the Project Level default **TargetServerVerion** is SQL Server vNext.  That doesn't work.

[image]

Changing this to any other value was the fix for me.

`Solution Explorer Window -> Right-click Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General -> TargetServerVersion = SQL Server 2016`